# In "informs3" cls, why theorem caption enable break line?

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

In "informs3" cls, why does the theorem caption enable break line?
template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-manufacturing-and-service-operations-management/nmthwmpdpryp
[image]

```
\begin{proposition}[Comparison with Independent Listing Under Endogenous Commission Rate]\label{prop4}
With an endogenous
commission rate, strategic listing leads to lower commission
revenue but higher advertising revenue for the platform relative
to independent listing. Overall, the platform (weakly)
benefits from strategic listing in the whole parameter space.
\end{proposition}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that replicates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `informs3` class loads the obsolete package `theorem`.

You can instead load `amsthm` that has better management of the optional argument to theorem-like environments and emulate the style used by `informs3`.

```
% don't load the obsolete package theorem
\expandafter\def\csname ver@theorem.sty\endcsname{}

\documentclass{informs3}

% load instead amsthm; we need to undefine proof first
\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}

% emulate the informs3 style
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{informs3}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {}          % HEADFONT
  {}          % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
  {\textsc{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}\textbf{ \thmnote{(#3).}}\@addpunct{\unskip.}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{informs3}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}[Comparison with Independent Listing Under Endogenous Commission Rate]
\label{prop4}
With an endogenous
commission rate, strategic listing leads to lower commission
revenue but higher advertising revenue for the platform relative
to independent listing. Overall, the platform (weakly)
benefits from strategic listing in the whole parameter space.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
This has no attribution argument.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]